# How to remove special character from the JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json, special-characters

I have following string int MySQL db.

```
Fireman�s drop
```

How to remove this types of special characters?

I tried to set header with following character set.when I encode this string into JSON its showing null as value

PHP Code

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');
....
$details='Fireman�s drop';//get from the db
$json_response=json_encode($details);
echo $json_response ;
```

OUTPUT

```
null
```

Expected

```
Fireman's drop
```

How to remove special characters from the JSON ?

Comment: Try query("SET NAMES utf8");

Comment: `charset=utf-8` and @SurabhilSergy suggestion before your select queries

Comment: If I set UTF-8 then its giving null value

Answer (score -1):

JSON in PHP only supports UTF-8 and will return false if given an invalid UTF-8 string which that will be if it contains special characters from ISO-8859-1.

Instead you should output `json_encode(utf8_encode($details))`

Comment: Its giving null as output